# Python: Extracting URLs using regex or other means

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I’m stumped on a problem. I have a large data frame where two of the columns are like this:

```
pd.DataFrame([['a', 'https://gofundme.com/ydvmve-surgery-for-jax,https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/890971913173991426/photo/1'],          ['b','https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/890971913173991426/photo/1,https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/890971913173991426/photo/1'],['c','https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/890971913173991430/video/1'] ],columns=['ID','URLs'])
```

What I’m trying to do is leave only the URL including the word “twitter” left in each cell and remove the rest. The pattern is that the URLs I want always include the word “twitter” and ends with “/” + a one-digit number. In the cases where there are two identical URLs in the same cell then only one should remain. Like this:

```
Test2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/890971913173991426/photo/1'],
 ['b','https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/890971913173991426/photo/1'],
 ['c','https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/890971913173991430/video/1'] ],columns=['ID','URLs'])

Test2
```

I’m new to Python and after a lot of googling I’ve started to understand that something called regex is the answer but that is as far as I come. One of the postings here at Stackoverflow led me to regex101.com and after playing around this is as far as I’ve come and it doesn't work:

```
r’^[https]+(:)(//)(.*?)(/)(\d)’
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions are certainly handy for such tasks. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) and online tools such as [regex101](https://regex101.com) to learn more.

Your current pattern is incorrect because:

- `^` Matches the following pattern at the start of string.
- `[https]+` This is a character set, meaning it will match `h`, `s`, `ps`, therefore any combination of one or more letters present in the `[]` brackets, and not just the strings `http` and `https` which is what you are after.
- `(:)` You don't need to put this `:` in a capturing group here.
- `(//)` `/` Needs to be escaped in regex, `\/`. No need for capturing group here either.
- `(.*?)` The `.*?` combo is often misused when a negated character set `[^]` could be used instead.
- `(/)` As discussed above.
- `(\d)` Matches and captures a digit. The capturing group here is also redundant for your task.

---

You may use the following expression:

```
https?:\/\/twitter\.com[^,]+(?<=\/\d$)
```

- `https?` Matches literal substrings `http` or `https`.
- `:\/\/twitter\.com` Matches literal substring `://twitter.com`.
- `[^,]+` Anything that is not a comma, one or more.
- `(?<=\/\d$)` Positive lookbehind. Assert that a `/` followed by a digit `\d` is present at the end of the string `$`.

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/vYlIQN/2).

---

Python demo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'https://gofundme.com/ydvmve-surgery-for-jax,https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/890971913173991426/photo/1'],
                   ['b','https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/890971913173991426/photo/1,https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/890971913173991426/photo/1'],
                   ['c','https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/890971913173991430/video/1'] ],columns=['ID','URLs'])

df['URLs'] = df['URLs'].str.findall(r"https?:\/\/twitter\.com[^,]+(?<=\/\d$)").str[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  ID                                                             URLs
0  a  https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/890971913173991426/photo/1
1  b  https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/890971913173991426/photo/1
2  c  https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/890971913173991430/video/1
```